# I see DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR on my ubuntu = “\” with php 7.2

Tags: php

under kubuntu 18 with php 7.2 I tried to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (my client works with windows)

```
$filePath            = $concurrentDirectory. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
```

But was VERY surprised when saved file had name :

```
weather\export\weather_1583310986.csv
```

looks like
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR on my ubuntu = “\”
Some misconfiguration on my side ?

```
$ php -v 
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2020 15:55:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
serge@athoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/maritime_industry/prime_watch$ php -a                           
Interactive mode enabled

php > echo DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
/
php >
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `$dir_separator = '/';` instead of `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` because `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` can cause a lot of problems.

Comment: This shouldn't happen normally, I tested it with 7.2 on Ubuntu 18 and it was showing / (as it should be). 

Can you provide us with the result of php -v 
And the result of 
php -a
echo DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

Comment: I added config params

Comment: What is $dir_separator ? param in .env?